# What podspec parameter to use for source file path?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I have a file hierarchy similar to this one:

[File hierarchy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cog8n.png)

And I need to capture in the visible area all the folders and files (swift and ObjC) that lie in the TestFramework. What podspec parameter to use for source file path? I try to use this:

```
s.source_files = "TestFramework/**/*"
```

Is the correct parameter I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, `s.source_files = "TestFramework/**/*"` is correct parameter for my situation.

- /** - matches directories recursively.
- /* - matches any file.

Sometimes it is necessary to limit the type of files that should be visible. For such situations, the following parameters are used:

`s.source_files = "TestFramework/**/*.{h,m,swift}"`